# Tool for automated packaging and deployments with Environment concept

Tags: xml, deployment, automation, teamcity, environment

We use **TeamCity** for builds\tests heavily.

As far as I can see TeamCity is not a proper tool for **packaging and deployments**.
Of course any command-line process can be initiated by TeamCity, but what we lack is a concept of "**Environment**", where to deploy.

Some tools like Nolio have this in arbitrary format.
So for example we can define Environment type for a project:

```
 1 app server:
  - IIS web site with:
     - Virtual Dir \ Web Application:
        - App Pool
        - .NET Framework version
  - Windows service with:
    - Name
    - Description

 1 db server:
  - db name
  - db user
  - db password
```

So all the environments (Dev, QA, PreProd, Prod) will have different parameters of these parts.
And during packaging step (for example to MSI by Wix) we use can use these parameters for creating MSI for a specific environement, for example update connectionString in Web.config.

Other projects can have different defitions of environments.
Probably XML format would be the best to describe such structure and values.

We have something like this implemented in NAnt scripts, where we have .build file per environment, which contains flat list of values. Then we `<xmlpoke>` the values into `Web.config` files. But this is quite difficult to maintain.

So now we are looking for some tool that can integrate with TeamCity (to get build artifacts), package them into installable MSI, which then can be easily deployed onto environemnt. Such tool must have this concept "Environment", allow to easily define the structure (see example above), allow to add\modify\delete environment instances, and then automatically use them when packaging\deployment.

Any ideas or your experience?

Comment: You have mentioned Nolio, which can be easily integrated with teamcity, so why not use it?

Comment: Nolio is a very expensive tool. My company is not going to approve it.

Answer (score 1):

My automated and manual deployments to different environments are actually done through Team City with MSDeploy and using Config Transformations.

This is the step-by-step guide I used, by Troy Hunt: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

And here's additional info on the transform syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

In this setup, each environment would be a different build configuration in your solution, as well as specific config transforms.